# Have i found a new method for the area of a pentagon?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

$$\begin{align}
h &= a\sin(36^\circ)\\
b &= 2\sqrt{a^2-h^2}\\ 
\triangle_1 &= \frac12bh\\
H &= b\sin(72^\circ)\\
\triangle_2 &= \frac12aH\\[4pt] 
PA &= \triangle_2 + 2\triangle_1  
\end{align}$$

where, as shown below,
$$\begin{align}
PA &= \text{the pentagon's area}\\
H,h &= \text{the perpendicular height}\\
b &= \text{the base}\\
a &= \text{one side's length}
\end{align}$$

It worked for me but is it original? I can't find it anywhere.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the “base” of the pentagon if not one side length?

Comment: does that image explain you question

Comment: Please edit your image, showing all names, like $a$, $b$, $H$, ....

Comment: @Dominique is that good enough i just need to see if it origanal

Comment: -1 for your name being DOGE

Comment: You're using $H$ (and $a$) to calculate $b$, and using $b$ to calculate $H$. How does that work? For finding the area of a non-regular pentagon you would probably want to split it into 3 triangles similar to this, [triangulating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) it whichever way is easiest, but I don't see the point of doing that in a regular pentagon where splitting it in 5 triangles is so much easier.

Comment: That is an error it is supposed to Lower case.

Comment: Also, I know there is an easier way I am just wondering if I have found a new and unique way. @JaapScherphuis

Comment: Why don't you use just the center?

Comment: Just read the previous comment @BobDobbs

Comment: This isn’t based on logic or simplicity just the fact that does it exist. That is what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of going about to define your specific unknowns may be original, as it complicates things by raising the square root function, the general idea however is not. The partitioning of an irregular pentagon into three triangles is a known technique f.e. for cases where five sides and two angles are given. Typically, you'd apply the Law of Cosines - represented at earlier times by the formula
$AB^{2}=CA^{2}+CB^{2}+2(CA)(CH)$ - and in more recent times its partner Law of Sines, to establish the needed unknowns, after which the procedure then works with Heron's formula for the area of triangles via their semiperimeter.

Comment: Thank that is what I wanted to hear